# Testing if two distributions are the same with Mann–Whitney U test given equal median

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

Given two independent variables $X$ and $Y$, I want to test if they follow the same distribution.

$H_0: F_X(.)=F_Y(.)$

$H_1: F_X(.)\neq F_Y(.)$

I do not want to test if their medians are the same.

Their shapes are shown below, look similar but can spot slight differences:

[image]

A concern is that I used the Mood's median test to check if their medians are equal, and it gives a high p-value so I cannot conclude their medians differ.

So when I use the MWU test, it may violate the consistency criterion that requires the medians to be different in order for the test to be consistent.

The MWU test does give a p-value $<$ 0.05

1. Should I then conclude the distributions are different based on this MWU test?
2. Should I be worried about consistency?
3. How should I test if the distributions are the same if the answer to 1. is no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. "*... may violate the consistency criterion that requires the medians to be different in order for the test to be consistent*"

   ... there's *no such requirement* to consider. Even if it were true, consistency is a property of a *test* not a sample, nor a population.

   Consistency is the condition that, *IF* the population effect is different from what is specified under $H_0$, as sample size increases toward infinity, the probability of the test rejecting $H_0$ goes to 1. Less formally, it's that *at sufficiently large sample size, the test rejects false nulls*.

   The test you're doing *is* consistent against the alternatives it's designed to test for. If it's testing what you wanted to test for, there's nothing to check on this, its consistency was proved many decades ago.
2. If you did the Mood test through some mistaken sense that there was a requirement to do so before using the test, it was a pointless exercise; there's nothing to check here - forget it.

   (I am extremely curious to know whether some book, paper, or other source actually suggested you needed to do this. If so, please indicate what it was, if possible I'd like to see what other egregious errors it contains to warn people about.)

   If you did it for some other reason - beware of using multiple tests of very similar hypotheses on the same data. It looks rather like significance hunting. You should look to test a single hypothesis rather than multiple variations of the same one. Figure out what you want to test for (before you collect data), and test *that*.

---

To address the specific questions you asked (albeit largely repeating what I just said):

> "*Should I then conclude the distributions are different based on this MWU test?*"

(i) Since you have $p\leq\alpha$, yes, you should reject the null of the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney; the test statistic is in the rejection region.

(ii) However, the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney is not a general test of distributional inequality and ought not be framed that way. It looks at the probability that a random value from one population will exceed a random value from the other population. In the test, $\frac{U}{n_1 n_2}$ is a sample estimate of that probability. If that probability is different from the probability of the converse direction (e.g. A's tend more often to be bigger when compared with randomly chosen B's) then in large samples you will tend to reject $H_0$, because the test is consistent against that specific alternative.

If the difference in the two distributions *does not produce any 'tends to be bigger' effect*, then the test simply lacks the ability to see it (it doesn't test any of those other kinds of alternatives).

(iii) If you *did* want a general test of distributional inequality rather than a test of 'tends to be bigger'-ness, you should not use this test, but instead one designed for that omnibus alternative (one of the various two-sample goodness of fit tests).

(Again, I am extremely curious to know whether some book, paper, or other source actually suggested that the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney was a test for general distributional inequality. If it was the same source, we already have our second egregious error to warn people against. It might well be a goldmine of other nonsense.)

> "*Should I be worried about consistency?*"

As a general principle? Probably. Most people seem to expect a test should be consistent -- at least up until they actually see its consequences happening (the fact that they always seem to reject with a really large sample), when it seems to make many people think something is wrong with the *test*, rather than perhaps with their choice to use a pure-equality null rather than something closer to what they thereby reveal that they wanted to test for.

In relation to a specific sample? It has nothing to say about that.

Comment: In the notes of a stat class, MWU is written to be the test for whether $F_X(.)=F_Y(.)$. The professor said that it is only consistent when the medians are different, this leads me into trying to test for their medians first. 

There is also an assumption written as "Assume $F_X(.)$ and $F_Y(.)$ are of the same shape and only differ in median".
This confuses me, because if they only differ in median but not shape, then wouldn't a median test suffice already?

In the post's example, so we are in the case of same median and MWU tests for shape (or the tendency to be bigger) only?

Comment: For (iii), if we cannot test general distributional inequality using MWU, then why is it valid to conclude the distributions are different in (i)? Why can the tendency to be bigger be valid to make such conclusion on distributional inequality in (i)?

And for a more general distributional inequality test, what are some good two-sample goodness of fit choices? I can only think of two-sample KS-test.

Comment: And what you mean by "omnibus alternative"? Are you referring to the alternative hypothesis having less restriction than the one in MWU? 

Does the $H_1$ of MWU require the medians be different? If yes, then in the post's example we reject null and yet their medians do not appear different (they do differ in real data slightly) from Mood's median test, would it then not violate the $H_1$ assumption?

Comment: **1**. "[omnibus](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/omnibus), adj *1.* of, relating to, or providing for many things at once." -- In this case because the alternative under discussion  (different distributions) would include differences in spread, shape, etc. $\,$ **2**. What conditions did he assume for the consistency claim? (or did he at least offer a reference?) The claim is not true in general -- it's quite easy to come up with a continuous counterexample, where under $H_1$ the medians are equal but the probability of rejection goes to 1 as sample size goes to infinity. ...

Comment: ... This happens because $P(A>B)$ is very far from $\frac12$ and the standard error of the sample estimate of $P(A>B)-\frac12$ goes to 0 as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: e.g. consider $f_A$ having two narrow humps of probability (each with probability $0.5-\epsilon$)  centered at $-1$ and $1$ and a very narrow hump at $0$ of prob. $2\epsilon$. Let $f_B$ be the same under $H_0$ and consider a sequence of alternatives where the two larger humps are both shifted right a bit while the teeny hump stays still. Consider the case where the bigger humps are shifted right by $0.5$ (assume they're only about $0.1$ wide). Under this alternative, $(P(A>B)-\frac12)$ is as close to $-0.25$ as we wish, with its asymptotic normal estimate having standard error $\propto 1/√n$.

Comment: ... Consequently, the square of the $Z$ score will go off to infinity. (NB assume that $n_A=n_B=n$; didn't have room for that in the comment just above.) ... so that's a case where the population medians are equal and yet the test is consistent against alternatives where $P(A>B)\neq\frac12$.

Comment: "then why is it valid to conclude the distributions are different in (i)" ... It's fine to conclude that the distributions are different *in the particular way* the test can see ($P(A>B)\neq P(A<B)$), not just in any possible way you wish. A two sample K-S test is fine, but there are others (e.g. two sample version of Anderson Darling: Pettitt, A. N. 'A two-sample Anderson-Darling rank Statistic,' *Biometrika*, **63**, 161-168, 1976)... I hope I covered everything that was still relevant after rebutting the claim about the median. I expect there's some nuance missing there ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... like an artificial restriction to pure-location-shift alternatives (which is neither required by the test, nor something you can determine from the samples; it would be an additional assumption that's not part of the general case).

Comment: Ah, found a bit I missed above: "In the notes of a stat class, MWU is written to be the test for whether FX(.)=FY(.)."

This combines the actual null (about that probability that it actually measures) with the assumptions for the test to have  exchangeability under the null to get the correct type I error rate. It is arguably correct *for this null* but has (directly) misled you into thinking the alternative is its complement, which is not the case. Writing the null this way also creates a slight problem when you consider the one-sided test. I keep the assumptions and the hypothesis distinct

Comment: One could as easily argue that the null in a t-test is FX(.)=FY(.), by pulling in assumptions into the null in the same fashion.